# Terraform, passing few subnets to autosecaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Have a code defining subnets as below:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)

  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, count.index)
  availability_zone       = element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.environment}-public-${element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

Later have a code defining autoscaling group:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ec2_testing" {
  availability_zones  = [data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]]
  vpc_zone_identifier = [element(aws_subnet.public.*id, count.index),]
  desired_capacity    = 1
  max_size            = 1
  min_size            = 1

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.ec2_testing.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
}
```

I'm getting error:

> A comma is required to separate each function argument from the next.

Edit: would need assign only one subnet.

How `vpc_zone_identifier` should be corrected? Help please.

Comment: `aws_subnet.public.*id` should be `aws_subnet.public.*.id`. Also you shouldn't be specifying the `availability_zones` parameter if you are also specifying the `vpc_zone_identifier` as it's unnecessary and will complicate logic (your current example will fail because those subnets aren't all in the same AZ).

Comment: And you either need `count` on that `aws_autoscaling_group` to be able to use `count.index` or you need to just use `aws_subnet.public.*.id[0]` similarly to how you are using the first AZ in the list of zones in the above parameter.

Comment: ydaetskcoR  - provided the right answer.

Comment: Thank you @ydaetskcoR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ydaetskcoR mentioned, two course of actions should be taken:

> `aws_subnet.public.*id` should be `aws_subnet.public.*.id`. Also you
> shouldn't be specifying the availability_zones parameter if you are
> also specifying the vpc_zone_identifier as it's unnecessary and will
> complicate logic (your current example will fail because those subnets
> aren't all in the same AZ)
>
> And you either need count on that aws_autoscaling_group to be able to
> use count.index or you need to just use `aws_subnet.public.*.id[0]`
> similarly to how you are using the first AZ in the list of zones in
> the above parameter.

Adding this for visibility.